# Register JPanel in radioButtonActionPerfomed

Tags: java, swing, listener, jradiobutton, buttongroup

Can I catch the panel name from `ActionListener`?

Here is some code:

```
void models (int paneNum, int tabNum, String eQuery, String str, String title) throws SQLException {

    intoModels[paneNum] = new JPanel();
    intoModels[paneNum].setBackground(c);
    intoModels[paneNum].setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));

    ResultSet rs = DataBase.setConnection().executeQuery(eQuery);
    ButtonGroup modelRadioGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    while (rs.next()) {

        JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(rs.getString(str));
        radio.addActionListener(new radioButtonActionPerformed());
        modelRadioGroup.add(radio);
        intoModels[paneNum].add(radio);
    }

    intoModels[paneNum].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), title));
    panelsTab[tabNum].add(intoModels[paneNum]);
}
```

And a listener code:

```
public class radioButtonActionPerformed implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        System.out.println("Selected radio: " + e.getActionCommand());
        selectedModel = e.getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

The interface: [image]

I can get selected radio, but I can't register from which panel. So I need to register the panel and save selected to the array on indexes 0 and 1 for the first and second panel.

Comment: 1. `Can I catch the panel name from ActionListener`== yes no issue, there are three - four ways, 2. `Here is some code:` == for better help sooner post an `SSCCE` / `MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `component.getParent()` method to get the parent.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object src=e.getSource();
            if(src instanceof JRadioButton){
                Container parent=((JRadioButton)src).getParent();
                if(parent instanceof JPanel){
                    System.out.println(parent.getName());
                }
            }
        }
```